# The Lubavitcher Rebbe and the name Nimrod

Tags: sources-mekorot, chabad, nimrod

Can anyone help me find the origin of the story [recorded here](https://www.inner.org/jewish-home-family/danger-the-mischievous-are-here):

> Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneerson instructed a ba’al teshuvah (returner
> to Judaism) whose name was Nimrod (נִמְרוֹד; meaning “Let us rebel”),
> that there was no need for him to change his name. Despite the fact
> that the Biblical Nimrod was the image of a negative rebel who
> rebelled against the Almighty, the modern Nimrod must now utilize this
> quality of rebelliousness positively and rebel against the counterfeit
> conventions of the world at large.

Answer (score 7):

[According to the Israeli Chabad website](http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?ArticleID=14273&CategoryID=2289), the person in question is R' Nimrod Chefetz who recounted this story during an interview at Chabad Online.  His account is brought [here](https://col.org.il/news/94290).

Comment: in that firsthand account, the Rebbe did not give a reason, just said there is no reason to change it.

Comment: @Menachem Correct. And then R' Nimrod added a suggestion for the reasoning. This seems to have evolved into the version that appears in the Q's sources.